# Tag a git commit and check tag exists in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

I currently have a VSTS build setup that automatically builds whenever a git repo changes. Can someone tell me if, rather than always build, if it is possible to selectively build based on tags created when changes were originally pushed to the remote repo:

e.g.

1) git push origin "My tag value"
2) VSTS build recognises the change in the repo
3) VSTS build scans down all commits since last change
4) If "My tag value" exists then do the build

If this is not an appropriate solution please recommend something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Add a trigger on `/refs/tags/<your tag name>`. A build will be triggered any time that tag is pushed.